# how to get category name instead of id

Tags: node.js, nodes

I need to show the member category name instead member category id in route. So how to get the member category name and send it instead member category id.

member category (Model)

```
const member_categorySchema = new mongoose.Schema({member_category_name: {
type: String,
default: null,
required: true,},member_category_slug: {
type: String,
default: null,
unique: true,},});
```

member detail (Model)

```
const memberSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
member_category_id: {
  type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  required: true,
  ref: "Member_Category",
},
member_name: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
oadd1: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
oadd2: {
  type: String,
  required: true,
},
```

I want to show the member category name which is in another collection (Route)

```
router.get("/all", async (req, res) => {try {
const memberDetails = await Member_Details.aggregate([
      // { $sort: {name: 1}}, 
      {$group: {
        _id: "$member_category_id", 
        member: {$push: {name: "$member_name", id: "$_id" }}
      }}
    ]);

    res.status(200).send(memberDetails);

if (memberDetails.length === 0) {
  res.status(333).json({
    success: false,
    message: "no timing found ",
  });
} else {
  res.status(200).send(memberDetails);
}} catch (error) {}});
```

I want this type of output.

```
[
{
    "_id": "625415aa2dd3df1feebdcf8b",
    "member": [
        {
            "name": "aadmin",
            "id": "62541cb4ecdbb4a81640475e"
        },
        {
            "name": "aadmin",
            "id": "62541d0aecdbb4a816404760"
        },
        {
            "name": "santosh",
            "id": "62541d1decdbb4a816404762"
        },
        {
            "name": "keshav",
            "id": "62541d29ecdbb4a816404764"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "62551ac0318da005a3ca1465",
    "member": [
        {
            "name": "node1",
            "id": "62551b44318da005a3ca146a"
        },
        {
            "name": "node2",
            "id": "62551b5d318da005a3ca146c"
        },
        {
            "name": "node3",
            "id": "62551b6f318da005a3ca146e"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id": "62541d43ecdbb4a816404766",
    "member": [
        {
            "name": "hemant",
            "id": "62541db6ecdbb4a81640476b"
        },
        {
            "name": "nikhil",
            "id": "62541dcbecdbb4a81640476d"
        }
    ]
}
```

]

Answer (score 0):

you can use .populate() Method

```
  router.get("/all", async (req, res) => {try {
    const memberDetails = await Member_Details.find().populate('Member_Category','name')
        ]);
    
        res.status(200).send(memberDetails);
    
    if (memberDetails.length === 0) {
      res.status(333).json({
        success: false,
        message: "no timing found ",
      });
    } else {
      res.status(200).send(memberDetails);
    }} catch (error) {}});
```